# How to unzip files with non-unique file names

Tags: python, unzip

I am re-writing a bash script that extracts aac files from .pencast files (which are really just .zip)...

```
import os
import glob
import zipfile

app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + os.sep
temp = app_path + 'AudioFiles'

for pencast in (glob.glob( app_path + '*.pencast')):
    f = zipfile.ZipFile(pencast, 'r')
    for number, audio in enumerate(f.namelist()):
        if 'aac' in audio:
            print(os.path.basename(pencast), number, audio)
```

which returns (so you can see what the files look like)

:!/usr/local/bin/python3 pencast.py

```
Cancer1-1.pencast 29 userdata/Sessions/PRS-a6959094a/audio-0.aac
Cancer1-1.pencast 32 userdata/Sessions/PRS-a695732e5/audio-0.aac
Cancer1-2.pencast 30 userdata/Sessions/PRS-a696fa7ab/audio-0.aac
Cancer1-2.pencast 33 userdata/Sessions/PRS-a699046df/audio-0.aac
Cancer1-3.pencast 32 userdata/Sessions/PRS-a699046df/audio-0.aac
Cancer1-3.pencast 35 userdata/Sessions/PRS-a696fa7ab/audio-0.aac
```

how can I unzip each of the files, give it a unique name ie

```
Cancer1-1-1.aac
Cancer1-1-2.aac
Cancer1-2-1.aac
```

...and have just the audio file moved to the 'AudioFiles' folder?

Comment: afconvert is a command line tool for converting audio files between formats. the aac files that are saved in the pencast files is not readable by itunes, so they need to be converted to mp4f

Comment: Ok, and what do you mean by "dumps the file"? The file *name*, or the unzipped file *contents*? Do you mean you want to flatten the directory structure of the zip archive, or something?

Comment: Please, reword and rework your questions. And IMO you are the only one who can answer if you should unzip with or without paths, it depends on what you need or want to do. As far as using afconvert or not, i'd use it with the subprocess module if there is no similar library for python, but don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use os.path.join to join paths.

And try something like this:

```
import os
import glob
import zipfile

def is_audio(file):
    return 'acc' in file

app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.chdir(app_path)
try:
    os.mkdir('AudioFiles')
except OSError:
    pass

for pencast in (glob.glob('*.pencast')):
    f = zipfile.ZipFile(pencast, 'r')
    for number, audio in enumerate(filter(is_audio, f.namelist())):
        basename = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(pencast)[0])
        newfilename = '{}-{}.acc'.format(basename, number)
        print(newfilename, number, audio)
        f.extract(audio, os.path.join('AudioFiles', newfilename))
```

I didn't try the code, it may contain errors, but i guess you'll get the point.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `def is_audio(file):` but I can see what it should do. I am also not familiar with using `filter` -> `enumerate(filter(is_audio, f.namelist()))`. This does not seem to return anything.

Comment: @user969617 with `def is_audio(file)` i'm declaring a function called `is_audio` that returns `True` if the `file` parameter has the substring `'acc'`. Basically i just moved the condition to make it more clear, instead of using `lambda` inline. `filter(is_audio, f.namelist())` returns a list of `f.namelist()` items that make `is_audio` return True. It replaces your inner `if` and saves me to make a counter.